# Jenkins Master and Node Setup - Issue with Builds

Tags: jenkins

I have set up my Master hub in a Remote System that I have access to and 5 people have registered as Nodes.

When all the nodes are idle, while the 5th person starts the execution, Jenkins actually triggers it in 1st PC?

Is there any way to overcome this? I Wish that while the 5th person starts the execution,
it should actually show browser execution in that PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'out-of-the-box' solution. But you can assign labels to the slave nodes and provide the same in the build configuration option `Restrict where this project can be run`. It will make the build execute on the desired nodes.